# How do I prove that the sequence $\frac{n}{n^2+1}$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Okay, I've been working on this problem but I'm stuck. I know what I have to do but as I'm proving this it doesn't seem right because I feel like I'm making it more complicated then it is.

I know that the limit does converge to 0

Comment: I can post pictures of my work is that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the limit in such a case in an intuitive way by dividing everything by the highest power of $n$, so
$$
\frac{n}{n^2+1} = \frac{1/n}{1+1/n^2} \rightarrow \frac{0}{1+0} = 0.
$$
To prove it formally we use the definition. $\forall\epsilon>0$ there must exist $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{n}{n^2+1} < \epsilon$ for $n\ge N$. Choose $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$, then we see that 
$$
\frac{n}{n^2+1} < \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon  
$$
for $n\ge N$. So the limit is indeed zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** you can use the fact that $$0\leq\frac{n}{1+n^2}\leq\frac1n$$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb N$.